# getting lat/long from address with geocode in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, geocoding, google-geocoder

I've got this working code that gets the lat/long combo from an address.

```
function testgeocode(){ 
    var responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('Form Responses');
    var range = responses.getRange('AD2:AD');
    var addresses = range.getValues();

    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();

    var destination = new Array();
    destination[0] = 31; // column + 1;
    destination[1] = 32; // column + 2;

    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder();
    var count = range.getHeight();
  
    for(i in addresses) {
        var location = geocoder.geocode(addresses[i]).results[0].geometry.location;
        responses.getRange(row, destination[0]).setValue(location.lat);
        responses.getRange(row++, destination[1]).setValue(location.lng);
        Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

I'm having difficulty modifying it so that the lat/long combo is outputted into one column with the format `'lat,long'`.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation / Issues:

- First of all, your code is quite inefficient. The reason for that is because you are using `getRange` and `setValue` inside a `for` loop but also two times per iteration. As it is explained in the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), the proper way to achieve your goal is to store the values into an empty array and then use `setValues` outside the `for` loop to set them to your sheet.
- The other modification is already mentioned in the other answer. You want to concatenate `location.lat`, `location.lng` separated by a comma.

### Solution:

```
function testgeocode(){ 
    var responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('Form Responses');
    var range = responses.getRange('AD2:AD');
    var addresses = range.getValues();

    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();

    var destination = new Array();
    destination[0] = 31; // column + 1;
    destination[1] = 32; // column + 2;

    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder();
    var count = range.getHeight();
    
    var data = [];
  
    for(i in addresses) {
        var location = geocoder.geocode(addresses[i]).results[0].geometry.location;
        data.push([location.lat + ',' + location.lng]) // new code
        Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
    
    responses.getRange(2,destination[0],data.length,1).setValues(data); // new code
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, currently you're getting the latitude and longitude values and writing them to different cells, but you want to have them both in a single cell, separated by a comma.
If that's the case, then you can make the following changes.

From:

```
var location = geocoder.geocode(addresses[i]).results[0].geometry.location;
responses.getRange(row, destination[0]).setValue(location.lat);
responses.getRange(row++, destination[1]).setValue(location.lng);
```

To:

```
var location = geocoder.geocode(addresses[i]).results[0].geometry.location;
responses.getRange(row, destination[0]).setValue(location.lat + ',' + location.lng);
```

You can adjust the parameters of [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) if you want to write it to a different cell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a custom function:

```
function a2c(address){
  var geo = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
  var loc = geo.results[0].geometry.location;
  return (loc.lat + ',' + loc.lng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another snippet the does the work:

```
function getLatLng(address) {
  // Geocode the address to get the location
  var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion('us');
  var response = geocoder.geocode(address);
  
  // Check if the geocode operation was successful
  if (response.status === 'OK') {
    var result = response.results[0];
    var lat = result.geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = result.geometry.location.lng;
    
    // Log the latitude and longitude for debugging
    Logger.log('Latitude: ' + lat + ', Longitude: ' + lng);
    
    return `${lat},${lng}`;
  } else {
    Logger.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + response.status);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your sheets like this `=getLatLng(A2)`